# Authorizing the admin in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication

Good day,

i am trying to check if the user is an admin if the user is an admin, he/she will be able to see the content on the page. If not then he/she will be redirected back to the home page. How can i do that? Should i use the backend code for that or can i check it on the frontend.

Route for admin page (this works perfectly fine):

```
router.get("/adminPanel", isAuth, isAdmin, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({
        title: "ADMIN PANEL",
    });
});
```

Login page:

```
const [user, setUser] = useContext(userContext);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(user));
    }, [user]);
    //handlesubmit
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/login", {
            email,
            password,
        })
            .then(response => {
                // localStorage.setItem(
                //  "token",
                //  JSON.stringify(response.data.token),
                // )((window.location = "/"));
                setUser({
                    token: response.data.token,
                    isAdmin: response.data.isAdmin,
                });
                window.location = "/";
                // console.log(response.data.token);
                // console.log(response.data.isAdmin);
            })

            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
```

setting the role and the token in the localstorage:

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        let admin = localStorage.getItem("admin");
        if (token) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
        } else if (token && admin) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("admin"));
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    };
    const logoutCallback = () => {
        // Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/logout");
        setUser({});
        localStorage.clear("token");
        window.location = "/";
    };
    const [user, setUser] = useState(getLocalStorage());
    useEffect(() => {
        setUser({ token: localStorage.getItem("token") });
    }, []);
    console.log(user);
```

Admin panel:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { userContext } from "../../App";
export default function Home() {
    const [user] = useContext(userContext);
    const [content, setContent] = useState("login plz to display the content");
    useEffect(() => {
        // if (user.isAdmin) {

        //  alert("is Admin");
        // }
        // Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users/adminPanel").then(response =>
        //  console.log(user),
        // );
        async function fetchProtected() {
            const result = await (
                await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/adminPanel", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        authorization: `Bearer ${user.isAdmin}`,
                    },
                })
            ).json();
            if (result.data) setContent(result.data);
        }
        fetchProtected();
    }, [user]);

    return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178365/12608714

Comment: @b3hr4d thank you for the response, but it doesnt help me